# what is the best way to parse, cant use optparse

Tags: python, parsing, optparse, command-line-arguments

I have a long script with several options to be choosen by the user and i was trying to use optparse, but i have read optparse does not accept several inputs in just one option.
I mean if i need to calculate the square of certain number, i would like to do it for several and not just for one. I mean to write in the command line, python math.py -i 4 5 6 54 and option -i to be executed over those numbers and returns 16 25 36 2916, and beyond that add more options, like python math.py -i 4 5 6 54 -d 4 5 6 54 and option -d also to be executed over those numbers. Could you help me to know what is the best option to parse?

thanks in advance

Comment: Please use sentences and periods (full stops) between them.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: yes, i have tried a lot of things, actually i have a main function with the optparse options, but it does not work, even if i write just one imput on every option (like python math.py -i 3 -d 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following [example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#callback-example-6-variable-arguments) in the docs.

It uses the `callback` option type in optparse. If you are able to, you should probably use `argparse` instead but that requires 2.7+.

The example code from the docs:

```
 def vararg_callback(option, opt_str, value, parser):
     assert value is None
     value = []

     def floatable(str):
         try:
             float(str)
             return True
         except ValueError:
             return False

     for arg in parser.rargs:
         # stop on --foo like options
         if arg[:2] == "--" and len(arg) > 2:
             break
         # stop on -a, but not on -3 or -3.0
         if arg[:1] == "-" and len(arg) > 1 and not floatable(arg):
             break
         value.append(arg)

     del parser.rargs[:len(value)]
     setattr(parser.values, option.dest, value)

[...]
parser.add_option("-c", "--callback", dest="vararg_attr",
                  action="callback", callback=vararg_callback)
```

It's a bit hairy but it does more or less what you want while still allowing you to use optparse for other stuff.

Comment: i already saw that example on the docs but, since i am new in python i do not know what to write on the [...], i have a main function within which are the parser.add_option (all the options), so, i have to write before that the text below def vararg_callback(option, opt_str, value, parser):???

Comment: what are the 4 values i should give to the function?

Comment: @marycrant: Hmm, okay. It would really help if you posted the code you have so far to your question. You can paste it at the bottom then select it and hit the `{}` button. Otherwise we'll just talk past each other :)

Comment: the thing is a very long code, but i manage to use action="append" to create lists of the arguments, and i just have to call the function again and again (python math.py -i 10 -i 2 -i 3)

Answer (score 2):

You can just read through `sys.argv` (an array of the command line arguments) and interpret them any way you like.